# What's the best way to use not exists and insert?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, exists

I am creating a stored procedure to check if username exists and if does not exists insert into user table then gets userid for the same username. This is what I was trying

```
alter Procedure Check_Name
 (
 --@idn integer,
@username varchar(25),
@password varchar(100)
--@role_id integer
)
As
Begin
INSERT INTO [user] (username,[password]) 
 SELECT username,[password]
 FROM [user] AS u
WHERE NOT EXISTS( 
SELECT idn FROM [user] AS t
WHERE u.username = t.username); 
End
```

When I try to execute it says zero rows affected..What is the problem

```
 execute Check_Name 'Pope', 'Life2Stressfull';
```

Comment: ok I changed that..then I got cannot insert null for my role_id so inserted a value. Now I'm getting Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ__user__F3DBC5722FAC4C26'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.user'. The duplicate key value is (Franz123). I dont get because the username I'm inserting is not 'Franz123'

Comment: `WHERE u.username = t.username AND t.username = @username`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:
`IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [user] AS t WHERE t.username = @username)
BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO [user] (username,[password]) VALUES (@username, @password) 
END`